Shadow on callouts
I'm using Quarto, with HTML output and I need to know: Is there any way to remove the green part, at the left of the word "Proof"?

My try:
---
format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true
    theme: darkly
---

::: {.hidden}
    ```{css, echo=FALSE}
p {
  text-align: justify
}

.callout.no-border {
  border-left-color: 4px solid #007bff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* sombra */
}
```
:::


::: {.callout-tip appearance='minimal' collapse='true' .no-border}
## Proof

:::


Could you please explain what your expected output should look like?
